# Joomla 3 : applying an alternative article layout on a whole category

Tags: templates, joomla

I know how to create all sort of alternative component, module, layout but for now I have to manually select the alternative layout for each new article. So how to apply a alernative article layout on a whole category ?

Thanks

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yeah, Sorry didn't knwo there is a specific J! section. Thks